# don't understand the derivation of logarithmic cost used in gradient descent

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic

I am learning Machine Learning.I have seen that in logistic regression there are two cost

1)$θ_j=θ_j − \frac{\alpha}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}(h_θ(x^{(i)})−y^{(i)})x^{(i)}$

2)$Cost(h_θ(x),y) = −ylog(h_θ(x))−(1−y)log(1−h_θ(x))$

While updating weights through gradient descent we use this $(h_θ(x^{(i)})−y^{(i)})x^{(i)}$ as derivation of cost function and after updating weights we calculate cost using $−ylog(h_θ(x))−(1−y)log(1−h_θ(x))$ cost. I don't understand that $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}( −ylog(h_θ(x))−(1−y)log(1−h_θ(x)) ) = (h_θ(x^{(i)})−y^{(i)})x^{(i)}$

according to my knowledge cost in the gradient is the derivation of logarithmic cost

Comment: I think you *might* be getting derivation and derivative mixed up. The process of getting a derivative is differentiation, not derivation.

But if this comment is wrong, I apologize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing cost (J) with the gradient of cost ($\nabla J$).

your first equation is equivalent to:

$$
\theta _j := \theta _j - \alpha /m \nabla J
$$

and then the second is the actual cost (J).

In each step, you are moving in the direction opposite of the gradient ($\nabla J$) and then the calculation of the cost is, probably, just to show that you are actually minimizing the value of the cost (J).

HTH

EDIT: Perhaps I misunderstood, but seems the OP wants the derivation of the derivative of the cost function.

To do that, first we have to note that
$$
h'_\theta (x) = x(h_\theta (x))(1 - h_\theta (x))
$$

Now, if we write the derivate of J above, we end up with (following normal rules of differentiation):

$$
\nabla_\theta J = -\frac{h'_\theta(x)}{(h_\theta (x))(1-h_\theta (x))}(y - h_\theta (x))
$$

If we substitute into the above the formula for $h'_\theta (x)$, we see that:

$$
\nabla J = x(h_\theta (x) - y)
$$

Comment: yes,  you are right I want to know what is the **∇** of cost function **J** where **J** = **−ylog(hθ(x))−(1−y)log(1−h(x))**

Comment: hθ(x) = 1 / 1 + e ^ (- θ * x) where θ = vector of features and x = vector of input values

Comment: I appreciate your efforts but I want just derivation of cost function(CF). In logistic regression or any ML algorithm, to reduce your cost to predict any value, you have to perform gradient descent on CF to get step size which will lead us to the global minimum. performing gradient descent on CF is nothing but a partial derivation(PD) of the cost function w.r.t θ. In logistic regression cost, the function is **−ylog(hθ(x))−(1−y)log(1−h(x))** .So if I want to reduce the cost, I have to have PD of above cost function. sources say that **(hθ(x(i))−y(i))x(i)** this the PD of cost function how?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand the question. It won't be possible to give all the steps of the derivation. However, I would encourage you to just differentiate the cost function w.r.t $\theta$. Keep in mind that, $\frac{d}{d\theta}log( h_\theta(x)) = \frac{h'_\theta(x)}{h_\theta(x)}$. if you do that then you should get the equation i have written for $\nabla_\theta J$. The **trick** is to recognise the particular form of $h_\theta(x)$ that will give you the identity above for $h'_\theta(x)$.

Comment: Okie that helped a lot thanks .....!!!

Comment: Cool. Please accept the answer if it clarified your question. Thanks.